# What does the -h switch do, when the reboot function is invoked in Bash/shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments, reboot

I read a forum post some time ago (unfortunately I don't have the link any more), that instructed me to invoke "reboot -h now" in Bash on a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) running the Unix-based [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) operating system.

It is supposed to reboot the system immediately.
What caught my eye though, was the *-h* switch.

There is no mention in the [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for the reboot function and I can't find anything about the switch on the Internet.

Since invoking the shutdown function together with the switch *-h* does not throw any errors, I have to assume, that the associated daemon (I believe it's [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)) does know the switch, making me conclude that it might be a deprecated feature, which is by default ignored today since it isn't needed any longer.

I also have to mention, that since I only used Raspberry Pi's with Linux up until now, I have no idea, whether this might even be a Raspberry-specific argument.

What is that specific switch supposed to do?

Comment: You might be getting better responses on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Just added the last paragraph to the question. I am only using Linux on my tons of raspberry pi's. I know that Raspbian is based off of Debian, like Ubuntu is, but I found nothing in other Debian forums either. So (if it exists) it might even be just a RPi specific thing

Comment: @PMF I wanted to move the question to the UNIX stack exchange but since someone already answered it, I can't any more. And now I suspect, that this question is giving me a question ban. I can't ask any more questions...

Comment: That souldn't give you a ban, since you have a positive score and also the question is just closed, not downvoted. But I don't know the details of those rules, I'm afraid.

Comment: Questions can't be migrated after more than 60 days, regardless of whether they're closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was for stopping hard disks before restarting. The reboot/poweroff/halt was instantaneous, and data could be lost. [sysvinit halt.c#L16](https://github.com/limingth/sysvinit/blob/b05ab2304caea3b6d9d1cc7e86f4bec6a24c1d2f/sysvinit-2.88dsf-subs/src/halt.c#L16) and [sysvinit htdown.c](https://github.com/limingth/sysvinit/blob/b05ab2304caea3b6d9d1cc7e86f4bec6a24c1d2f/sysvinit-2.88dsf/src/hddown.c#L506).

Nowadays, it's just ignored by systemd [systemd systemctl-compat-halt.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/788733428d019791ab9d780b4778a472794b3748/src/systemctl/systemctl-compat-halt.c#L123):

```
            case 'i':
            case 'h':
                    /* Compatibility nops */
                    break;
```

Comment: (Deleted my previous comment, as it doesn't really fit with `systemd` actively ignoring `-h`.)

Comment: I _think_ (or vaguely remember from experience) that reboot system call was literally instantaneous, giving IDE drivers no time to sync, so a ioctl was invented to sync IDE drivers, so it was everywhere recommended adding `-h` to call that ioctl to sync IDE drivers. I would expect that today kernel is smart enough.